# Weaker Hausdorff topology on a compact set is the original topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I've read about a theorem which states something like

$(X, \tau)$ locally convex space, $A \subset X$ $\tau$-compact. Let $\sigma$ be a weaker Hausdorff topology on $X$. Then $\tau$ coincides with $\sigma$ on A.

Can someone state this proposition properly? Maybe $X$ could be a general topological space. I've only read about it in the context of locally convex spaces. Thank you.

Comment: By locally convex do you include Hausdorff?

Comment: @FShrike Probably, or the statement is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau)$ a compact topological space. Let $\sigma\subseteq \tau $ a topology on $X$ such that $(X, \sigma)$ is Hausdorff. Then $\sigma=\tau$.

**Proof**: The identity map $(X, \tau)\to (X, \sigma)$ is continuous (since $\sigma\subseteq \tau)$, $(X, \tau)$ is compact and $(X, \sigma)$ is Hausdorff, so the identity map is a homeomorphism. In particular, it is open.

Comment: It is interesting to view this result as saying that a compact Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ is highly unstable: if $\sigma$ is any topology on $X$ such that $\sigma\varsubsetneq\tau$, then $(X,\sigma)$ is not Hausdorff.  On the other hand, if $\sigma\varsupsetneq\tau$, then $(X,\sigma)$ is not compact.